# fan out each row into multiple rows per keys in a JSON column

Tags: json, postgresql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_stats (username varchar, metadata_by_topic json);
INSERT INTO user_stats VALUES ('matt', '{"tech":["foo","bar"],"weather":"it is sunny"}');
INSERT INTO user_stats VALUES ('fred', '{"tech":{"stuff":"etc"},"sports":"bruins won"}');
```

The top-level keys in metadata_by_topic are always strings (e.g. "tech", "weather"), but the values under them are arbitrary json. I'd like a query that maps these top-level keys to their own column, and the json values to a different column, like so:

```
username     | topic     | metadata
-----------------------------------
matt         | tech      | ["foo","bar"]
matt         | weather   | "it is sunny"
fred         | tech      | {"stuff":"etc"}
fred         | sports    | "bruins won"
```

where username and topic are both of type VARCHAR and metadata is of type JSON. This:

```
select * from json_each((select t.metadata_by_topic from user_stats as t));
```

only works if I add LIMIT 1 the inner select, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: This is a better method

```
select username, key, metadata_by_topic->key
from
  (select username,  
      json_object_keys(
            (select t.metadata_by_topic from user_stats as t where t.username=us.username)
      ) AS KEY,
      us.metadata_by_topic
    from user_stats us
  ) x
```

Comment: I don't think this degree of nesting will be performant enough for my application, but you answered the problem as asked, so thank you.

Comment: Have you tested the performance? I only ask because the postgres optimizer is an amazing thing sometimes.